# generate a sentence based upon values of other cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a tool that generates a sentence based upon an established frameworks for consistency.

I have managed to do it for the most part using the following formula:

="The loudspeaker shall meet or exceed the following performance characteristics: "&IF([@[Frequency Response]]>"",lspk_spec[[#Headers],[Frequency Response]]&" of "&[@[Frequency Response]]&"; ", "")&IF([@[Sensitivity (1W '@ 1m)]]>"",lspk_spec[[#Headers],[Sensitivity (1W '@ 1m)]]&" of "&[@[Sensitivity (1W '@ 1m)]], "")

What the formula is doing is creating a test specification for a speaker.  The first part is the intro text, the second is the column header (common to all rows) and third is the value of that column specific to a given row.  The last two repeat as required for the required number of attributes.

Unfortunately I quickly hit the limitations of nested "if" statements (which is 7) or 30 when using concatenate.  It is also difficult to edit in the formula tool bar.

Now to take this to the next level, I also desire to have the VBA script skip empty cells if possible.

I am fairly proficient with formulas however have very limited experience when it comes to VBA.

It might also be worth while to note, this is in a table in excel, not just a standard sheet.

here is a link to the spreadsheet simplified for easy understanding.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3219967/Trial%20AV%20XLS%20Spec.xlsx

I appreciate any assistance you can lend.

Cheers,

Comment: As a formula based approach i might recommend a number of helper columns to calculate each sentence fragment seperately then simply & them all together. This give the added bonus of being able "skip" empty cells.

Answer (score 0):

If I got right your request, this code could help you to solve your issue:

```
Function SpecificationText(titles As Range, specs As Range)
'Check input integrity
'titles and specs ranges must have same length
If titles.Count <> specs.Count Then
   SpecificationText = CVErr(xlErrRef)
   Exit Function
End If
'titles and specs ranges must be of type 1 x n columns
If titles.Rows.Count > 1 Or specs.Rows.Count > 1 Then
   SpecificationText = CVErr(xlErrRef)
   Exit Function
End If


'Create the string combinating titles and specs only when specs is not empty
textSpecs = ""

For n = 1 To specs.Count

    If specs(n) <> "" Then

        If textSpecs <> "" Then
            textSpecs = textSpecs & ", "
        End If

    textSpecs = textSpecs & titles(n) & " " & specs(n)
    End If

Next

SpecificationText = textSpecs & "."

End Function
```

Please note that the formula uses two arguments that are two ranges: the titles and the specification. The two ranges should contain the same number of columns and only one row. I wrote some code to check this condition at the beginning. In case it fails you get !#REF error. I have put also some punctuation management (commas to divide phrases made by column header and specification and final full stop).

If you want to add an intro you may write in the cell a formula like this:

```
="Your intro: " & SpecificationText(A4:A10,C4:C10)
```

In case you need further help, please let me know.